# IOS - In App Purchase Retore completed transaction

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, restore

I had been going through the documentation many times and still not sure how to go about this. From `In App Purchase Programming guide - Restore Purchased Product`:

> In most cases, all your app needs to do is refresh its receipt and
>   deliver the products in its receipt. The refreshed receipt contains a
>   record of the user’s purchases in this app, on this device or any
>   other device. However, some apps need to take an alternate approach
>   for one of the following reasons:
>
> If you use Apple-hosted content, restoring completed transactions
>   gives your app the transaction objects it uses to download the
>   content.

Does that means if I am using Apple-hosted content, I don't need to refresh its receipt and call `restore completed transaction` straight to retrieve my previous download product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to do it.

What the text you quoted means is that the receipt contains the **information** about what in-app products the user purchased, but the receipt does not contain the **content**.

So if you use Apple-hosted content, you need a mechanism to download said content. That content is not provided when you refresh the receipt. It is downloaded however when you use the various restore functions.

Comment: come to think of it, how do we keep track of the downloaded content? I mean, we have to move it into document directory and probably into new folder. Do Apple server keep track of that? Or we have to create a system to keep track of product id wether we delete it or move it to folders?

Comment: You should probably post a new question. In short, no, Apple doesn't keep track of it, you have to code your own system. And, once downloaded, you have to move the content into NSApplicationSupportDirectory and not the Documents directory (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html). A good tutorial that helped me a lot: http://xinsight.ca/blog/iap-content-download-in-ios6/